# calculate the sum and display in label using asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Table name: **sample**

```
ID| Name  | Amount
--|-------|-----
1 | sam   |  12
----------|-----
2 | samp1 |  25
```

Markup

```
 <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblsupcount"></asp:Label>
```

how to write coding in c#

Comment: Will need a little more from you here, you tagged JavaScript, does this suggest you want to do the work client side?

Comment: did you try anything? show some efforts that you put in. It's gonna be a simple Sql query with `SUM` function.

Comment: I would add to your question the source of the data you want to display. If the source is static (ie. always the same) then look into HTML/CSS on how to use the <table> tag. If the source is dynamic (ie. it comes from a database and changes for every user) then look at the GridView control to create tables from a data source.

Answer (score 1):

```
SqlConnection conn=new SqlConnection("your DB connection string"); //connect to the database here
conn.Open();
SqlDataAdapter sda=new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM sample",conn);
conn.Close();
DataTable dt= new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
lblsupcount.Text=dt.Rows[0][0].toString();
```

Comment: where is connetionString ??/

Comment: I don't have his connection string, I assumed he could do that himself. Anyway, I provided the format for it